# c# SoapHttpClientProtocol get raw xml of request

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I need to invoke soap call. I add web link and enter wsdl and Visual studio generates a class derived from `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol`.

But when i call method (f.i. `CreateOrder`) it throws `FormatException`. But call from SoapUI passes succesfully. What I need is to get raw xml request to analyse what's wrong. Can I get it?

Comment: How are you invoking your service? If it's old style web services you could create a SoapExtension (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w06t139(v=vs.100).aspx). If WCF, you might like to look at IClientMessageInspector (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733786.aspx). Or as a simpler approach, have you tried Fiddler?

Comment: This is third party web service on soap not on .net stack

Comment: The SoapExtension and IClientMessageInspector both live with your code, running client side - so you should be able to still use either approach, given that you're using C#